# How to add a row to mention the names of the dataframes after we concatenate them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 dataframes with the same format.

[image]

Then I combine them horizontally and get

[image]

I would like to add a row to denote the name of each dataframe, i.e.,

[image]

I get above form by copying the data to MS Excel and manually adding the row. Is there anyway to directly do so for displaying in Python?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph'], 'Age': [20, 21]}  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data) 

data = {'Name': ['John', 'Kim'], 'Age': [15, 17]}  
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = {'Name': ['Paul', 'Dood'], 'Age': [10, 5]}  
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data) 

pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `key` parameter in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis = 1, keys=('df1','df2','df3'))
print (df)
      df1       df2       df3    
     Name Age  Name Age  Name Age
0     Tom  20  John  15  Paul  10
1  Joseph  21   Kim  17  Dood   5
```

Answer (score 1):

The row is actually a first-level column. You can have it by adding this level to each dataframe before concatenating:

```py
for df_name, df in zip(("df1", "df2", "df3"), (df1, df2, df3)):
    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(((df_name, col) for col in df))

pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Very nich case, but you can use Multindex objects in order to be able to build want you want.

Consider that what you need is a "two level headers" to display the information as you want. Multindex at a columns level can accomplish that.
To understand more the code, read about [Multindex objects in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html). You basically create the labels (called levels) and then use indexes to point to those labels (called codes) to build the object.

Here how to do it:

```
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph'], 'Age': [20, 21]}  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data) 

data = {'Name': ['John', 'Kim'], 'Age': [15, 17]}  
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = {'Name': ['Paul', 'Dood'], 'Age': [10, 5]}  
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data) 

df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['df1', 'df2', 'df3'], ['Name', 'Age']], codes=[[0, 0], [0, 1]])
df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['df1', 'df2', 'df3'], ['Name', 'Age']], codes=[[1, 1], [0, 1]])
df3.columns = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['df1', 'df2', 'df3'], ['Name', 'Age']], codes=[[2, 2], [0, 1]])
```

And after the concatenation, you will have:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis = 1)
```

[image]